# Why bind and unbind don't work as expected

Tags: jquery

I was originally doing this:

```
$('div.ocontainer').each(function() {
    var o = $(this);
    var newCode = $(this).attr('id');
    if (o.parents('.ocontainer').length != 0) {
        var oldCode = o.parents('.ocontainer').attr('id');
        console.log('unbinding '+oldCode);
        $('#'+oldCode+' a').each(function() {
            $(this).unbind('click')
            })
    }
    console.log('binding '+newCode);
    $('#'+newCode+' a').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            decideStMethod(newCode);
        })
    })
})
```

...but the `unbind` was not working. I ended up with the original code being passed in the click function. So I changed to using name spaced events:

```
$('div.ocontainer').each(function() {
    var o = $(this);
    var newCode = $(this).attr('id');
    if (o.parents('.ocontainer').length != 0) {
        var oldCode = o.parents('.ocontainer').attr('id');
        console.log('unbinding '+oldCode);
        $('#'+oldCode+' a').each(function() {
            $(this).unbind('click.'+oldCode)
            })
    }
    console.log('binding click.'+newCode);
    $('#'+newCode+' a').each(function() {
        $(this).bind('click.'+newCode,function() {
            decideStMethod(newCode);
        })
    })
})
```

...and now the `unbind` works but the subsequent `bind` does not. Note, though, that the line that is doing the `bind` DOES work if it's not subsequent, that is, if it is not preceded by an `unbind`.

The use of this is that first a region of the page is processed, and the binding is done on the links within it. Then, the subregions are processed, and if one of them has its own code, the region's handler must be unbound and replaced with the subregion's. The reason for all of this is that the subregions are placed in the region dynamically, so what they will be is never known in advance. Oh, and just in case it matters, this is jQuery 1.72

So:

```
<div id="region" class="ocontainer">
   <div id="subregion" class="ocontainer">
      <a>
```

On the processing of region, the link is bound to click.region and a function passing 'region'. Then, click.region should be unbound, which it is, and click.subregion bound in its place with a function passing 'subregion', which does not happen.

Comment: Functions such as `.bind()` (or `.on()` in jQuery 1.7+), `.unbind()`, etc apply to **all** of the elements in the jQuery object they're called on, so you don't need to use `.each()` to iterate over them and bind the events individually - jQuery handles that for you implicitly.

Comment: Also, can we see a. the binding for the old events (the ones you're unbinding) and b. the relevant HTML that this code is running against, please?

Comment: Try to explain what are you actually planning to do.

Comment: `bind('click.'+newCode);` does not seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is first, `bind()` and `unbind()` are deprecated functions. Use `.on()` and `.off()` instead.

Here is an example with some improvements too.

```
$('div.ocontainer').each(function() {
    var o = $(this);
    var newCode = o.attr('id'); //Use cached version instead
    if (o.parents('.ocontainer').length != 0) {
        var oldCode = o.parents('.ocontainer').attr('id');
        console.log('unbinding '+oldCode);
        $('#'+oldCode+' a').each(function() {
            o.off('click', "#"+oldCode); //Turn off the event handler
        })
    }
    console.log('binding click.'+newCode);
    $('#'+newCode+' a').each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', "#" + newCode, function() {
            decideStMethod(newCode);
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: For some reason this fails on all clicks when I use .on/.off instead of .bind/.unbind   I did verify (`console.log($().jquery`) that it is jQuery 1.7.2

Comment: Ah, the .off line should be $(this).off and not o.off, but having done that, I'm in the same position, binds work, unbinds work, but binds on an element after that element gets an unbind do not work.

Comment: @Ayen, First explain what you are trying to do in plain words. That was just an example, not a working piece of code.

Comment: I think the 3 lines of HTML and the description with them are as plain as I can get with a description. Probably if the requirement were any more plain I wouldn't have the problem :)   I did get it to work. Your example was helpful, thanks.